# MySQL query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to make this query from PHP:

```
set @row:=-1;
SELECT * FROM `tablename`
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT `id` FROM ( 
        SELECT @row:=@row+1 AS rownum, `id` FROM ( 
            SELECT id FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `id` DESC 
        ) 
            AS sorted 
    ) as ranked WHERE rownum % 14 = 0 
) AS subset ON subset.id = `tablename`.id LIMIT 24;
```

Works fine in PHPMyAdmin, but I have an error for the "set@row=-1;". :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide the PHP you're using and the full error message.

Comment: Show us your PHP code

Comment: `mysqli_query`, which you are probably using, accepts only one query. You have two queries here. You should use `mysqli_multi_query` (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). Also, maybe you are calling the `set` command before you have closed the result set of a previous query to `mysqli_query` . This will also raise an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be trying to use these statements in a single `mysqli_query` statement. These are multiple statements; you need to query them separately, while using PHP code.

However, you can also convert these two queries into a single query using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename`
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT `id` FROM ( 
        SELECT @row:=@row+1 AS rownum, `id` FROM ( 
            SELECT id FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `id` DESC 
        ) AS sorted 
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row := -1) AS user_init_vars 
  /* shifted SET statement to the above line (remove the comment before using) */
    ) as ranked WHERE rownum % 14 = 0 
) AS subset ON subset.id = `tablename`.id LIMIT 24;
```

Comment: Sorry, my SQL level is less than basic, the idea I think is very good but not to put in "user_init_vars"

Comment: @fabian what do you mean ? It is just an alias name for the derived table being used to initialize the user-defined variable.

Comment: XD, sorry, my level is too basic...!!!

Works very fine!!!

Many thanks!!!!

Comment: Finally this is the query...

SELECT * FROM `tablename` INNER JOIN ( SELECT `id` FROM ( SELECT @row:=@row+1 AS rownum, `id` FROM ( SELECT id FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `id` DESC ) AS sorted CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @row := -1) AS NAME ) as ranked WHERE rownum % 3 = 0 ) AS subset ON subset.id = `tablename`.id LIMIT 12

BUUUT, I need INVERT the general result... :(

Comment: Solved, inverted on JQuery ;)